# Can't run MusicStore sample

Tags: docker, sample, steeltoe

when I'm trying to run the MusicStore sample described [here](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/master/MusicStore) the download of docker images breaks with following error.

Can someone confirm this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions need to be updated.  There were two Config Server paths `steeltoeoss/configserver` and `steeltoeoss/config-server`.  This was confusing and the first one was cleaned up.  Please use `steeltoeoss/config-server` now.

A ticket will be created to fix the readme.

Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Update:  The ticket has been resolved, readme and yaml have been updated.